# Doubts about Pointer to a function

Tags: function, function-pointers

```
 #define IAP_LOCATION 0X1F00FFFF

 int iap_program(unsigned int target_addr, unsigned int source_addr)
 {
   typedef void(*IAP)(unsigned int[], unsigned int[]);
   IAP iap_entry;

   iap_entry = (IAP) IAP_LOCATION;

   command[0] = 50;                              // prepare the sector for write operation
   command[1] = 7;                               // start sector no
   command[2] = 7;                               // end sector no
   iap_entry (command, result); 
 }
```

In the above code i am confused about the line IAP iap_entry;IAP is a function pointer.What does IAP iap_entry and  iap_entry = (IAP) IAP_LOCATION; mean?

i am used to using function pointers in the style given below

```
 float funct(float num1, float num2 ) 
 {
  return num1 * num2; 
 }

 typedef float(*pt2Func)(float, float);

 pt2Func *FnPtr = &funct;

 float result = (*FnPtr)(2.0, 5.1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`IAP` is *not* a function pointer. It is a function pointer *type*. (in the same way that `int` is a numeric type, not a number itself)

`iap_entry` *is* a function pointer, of type `IAP`.

`(IAP) IAP_LOCATION` is also a function pointer, of type `IAP`, and was produced by casting an integer into a pointer.